# How can I delay the setting of a variable by 30 seconds in my AngularJS application?

Tags: angularjs

I have this code in my application:

```
putTestQuestionResponses()
   .finally(() => processingPutTestQuestion = false);
```

putTestQuestionResponses() returns a promise.

Is there a way that I could make it so that"

- If the promise is resolved: processingPutTestQuestion = false
- If the promise is rejected: 30 second delay then processingPutTestQuestion = false

Comment: Use `$timeout` or $interval`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
putTestQuestionResponses().then(
    //resolved
    function(){
        processingPutTestQuestion = false;
    },
    //rejected
    funciton(){
        $timeout(function(){
            processingPutTestQuestion = false
        }, 30000);
    }
);
```

And remember to inject $timeout

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.then` block to resolve the promise. Something like below :

If you are getting a response from an AJAX call :

```
    getResponsePromise.then(function(data){
      //this is the success case where the response is resolved
      processingPutTestQuestion = false ;
    }, function(err){
//this is the error block
       $timeout( function() {
     processingPutTestQuestion = false ;
    }, 30000)
    });
```